# how can i dispaly "<html>" as output on browser

Tags: html

I want to display following output on browser. Please suggest me, how can I generate following output on browser
output should :- `<html>`

I have used following code

```
 <html>
 <head></head>
 <body>
   <html>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: There are literally hundreds of answers to variations of "how to I escape HTML characters?" on stackoverflow. I suggest you try searching for an answer before asking a question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape `<` and `>` using entities:

```
&lt;html&gt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `&lt;` and `&gt;` for `<` and `>`:

```
&lt;html&gt;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the HTML content you want visible to the user:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    &lt;html&gt;
</body>
</html>
```